# I'm having problems accessing a $resource variable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-resource

I made a request for a php getting a JSON string, when I access the string in my template using `$ctrl.respostas[0].status` it returns a string with a value, but when I try to use the same model in my controller (`this.respostas[0].status`), it came nothing, I need to check the answer in my controller, but I don't know how, any one can help me?

```
Template: 
<p>respostas: {{$ctrl.response}}</p>
<p>confere: {{$ctrl.test}}</p>
<p>status: {{$ctrl.response[0].status}}</p>
```

Controller

```
angular.
    module('tela').
    component('tela', {
        templateUrl: 'tela/tela.template.html',
        controller: ['Request',
            function telaController(Request, ̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶) {
                this.test = "ola";
                this.id = "1";
                this.validate = function validate() {
                    this.response= Request.save({id: this.id},[]);
                    this.test = "algo";
                    this.test = this.response[0].status;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Request

```
angular.
  module('request.Request').
  factory('Request', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return $resource('./php/acessing.php',{
                teste: "@id",
            }, {
                save: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    hasBody: true,
                    isArray: true,
                    cache: false
                }
            });
        }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that invoking a [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage) object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

The HTML template shows the data because the interpolation bindings `{{ }}` check the object every digest cycle and update the DOM. The controller on the other hand needs to use the attached promise to examine the data:

```
app.component('tela', {
    templateUrl: 'tela/tela.template.html',
    controller: ['Request',
        function telaController(Request, ̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶) {
            this.test = "ola";
            this.id = "1";
            this.validate = function validate() {
                this.response= Request.save({id: this.id},[]);
                var promise = this.response.$promise;
                promise.then(data => {
                    console.log(data[0].status);
                    console.log(this.response[0].status);
                });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

From the Docs:

> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: The promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
>   On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server.
>
>   On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object.
>
> [— AngularJS $resource API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)